# How can I change my postgresql WAL file size?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.4

How can I change my PostgreSQL WAL file size as my wish. By default at **pg_wal** directory postgres generate 16MB WAL files. I try to change using max_wal_size, min_wal_size parameter. But I think it is not right parameter to change. Necessary details given in the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an old and outdated version like 9.4, your only option is to build PostgreSQL from source and configure it with

```sh
./configure --with-wal-segsize=1024
```

Then you have to dump and restore the cluster to that new installation.

With current versions. You could simply shut down PostgreSQL cleanly (important!) and run `pg_resetwal` with the appropriate option.

Upgrade!

Comment: How can I define it, I am confused of syntax for 20MB WAL size?  pg_resetwal --wal-segsize=10240

Comment: oh ok I understood pg_resetwal --wal-segsize=2,4,8,16,32 like this am I right? @Laurenz Albe that means power of 2^0, 2^1, 2^2,2^3?

Comment: Yes, precisely: it is in MiB, and it must be a power of two.